# Linux fuse changed from ntfs, 1TB portable disk

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ntfs, fuse, portable-harddrive

How can I change the fuse file system type to NTFS on portable disk?
The portable HDD was working on Windows but when I plugged it to Linux Ubuntu Windows does not recognise it.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you wanting to use FUSE to mount your NTFS drive or change to using a kernel NTFS implementation? What Linux distro are you using? Do you want to share a log snippit from when you plug the drive in?

Comment: Disk was NTFS. Now file system shows as fuse. I need it back as NTFS. Ubuntu

Comment: FUSE is not a filesystem, its an abstraction layer allowing you to mount file systems (including NTFS) in user space. The filesystem probably has not changed but may have minor corruption or a wrong partition type. What do your logs show when you plug in the drive?